# Woocomerce - getting subscription with sku and quantity for all user

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

im currently in need for a sql, that fetches me the current subscriptions for an user. To identify it, i need only the userid, the quantity and the sku of the product. I tried it now for a few days, but tbh the database structure is a mess and i cant get the right solution it seems.

My current approach is, to have two views, one for the orders they bought and one for the quantity of this orders. these views are joined, but it seems that there are results missing.

Here is my sql for the bought_orders, can anyone hint me in the right direction?

```
Create view bought_orders as SELECT distinct products.sku,
                postmeta.meta_value        as user_id,
                #order_item_meta.meta_key, #as quantity,
               order_items.order_id
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items as order_items

         LEFT JOIN
     wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta
     ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id

         LEFT JOIN
     wp_posts AS posts
     ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID

         LEFT JOIN
     wp_postmeta AS postmeta
     ON posts.id = postmeta.post_id

         LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id        AS product_id,
           post_name AS sku
    FROM wp_posts
    WHERE post_type = 'product'
) AS products ON products.product_id = order_item_meta.meta_value

WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_subscription'
  AND posts.post_status = 'wc-active'
  AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
  AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
  AND postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user';
```

Comment: What is the error of your SQL script?

Comment: Ever figure this?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I hacked this together based on code found elsewhere, and I'm sure that it could be paired down and a bit more efficient, but it works for me now...

```
global $wpdb;

$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT sum(subscription_line_items.qty)
        
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS product 
    
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT wcoitems.order_id AS subscription_id, wcoimeta.meta_value AS product_id,
        wcoimeta.order_item_id, wcoimeta3.meta_value AS qty 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS wcoitems 
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS wcoimeta 
        ON wcoimeta.order_item_id = wcoitems.order_item_id 
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS wcoimeta3 
        ON wcoimeta3.order_item_id = wcoitems.order_item_id 
        WHERE wcoitems.order_item_type = 'line_item' 
        AND wcoimeta.meta_key = '_product_id' 
        AND wcoimeta3.meta_key = '_qty' 
    ) AS subscription_line_items ON product.id = subscription_line_items.product_id 
    
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT({$wpdb->prefix}postmeta.post_id) AS wppm_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
    
    ) AS subscription_meta ON subscription_meta.wppm_id = subscription_line_items.subscription_id
    
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS subscriptions 
        ON subscriptions.ID = subscription_line_items.subscription_id 
    
    WHERE product.post_type = 'product' 
    AND subscriptions.post_type = 'shop_subscription' 
    AND subscriptions.post_status = 'wc-active'");
```